# How to delay Adding elements to Recyclerview adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create a chat bot. I need to simulate an interactive response from app.The response doesn't come from sever it's embedded inside app.
I'm using **recycleview** to implement chat UI, I need to delay every message for a specific time so user feels that someone is actually talking to him.

```
   private void displayNewMessage(ArrayList<ChatMessage> messages) {
        for (int i = 0; i < messages.size(); i++) {
            chatMessages.add(messages.get(i));
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }
```

The previous method is used to push an array of messages to user, how can I delay adding every element to adapter. or push them all to adapter and delay displaying them in adapter it self?

I tried to use Handler but it didn't work, it delays all messages and pushes them all together.

Answer (score 2):

It's a logical question more than programming.

At first why `it delays all messages and pushes them all together` - because the for loop, it will add them to adapter at once.

An alternative solution is to use handler on some where else suppose on user sending message thread.

assume we have the user `sendMessageButton` we can make some nice logic there.

We will add message and a time for wait, you can make it `Random` time, e.g:

```
 sendMessageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    chatMessages.add(newMessage);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            },random);

        }
    });
```

Comment: The problem that it is not one message, it's an array of messages, it's something like google assistant, the user has choices and if he selects one of them the choice is sent to a method to determine the suitable response and return a list of messages. your solution will be OK if user has a button like "next" so we can manage the delay on button click

Comment: @KhaledAbdElnaser then you have to provide us, how you used `displayNewMessage` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop after adding data to arrat put delayedpost on recycler and call notify inside the run method, this will simulate delay for each message, instead of delay and then showing all messages at once

Answer (score 0):

You can use Handler.post delay(new Runnable(),3000);
You put your code under their runnable interface run method it will start with after delay seconds.

Comment: The whole response will be delayed for delay seconds, but then it will be pushed all together to adapter. this is doesn't simulate real chat